# Problems with ContinuedFractionK

Tags: series-expansion, recursion, continued-fractions

I am interested in calculating the following series

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{ \frac{ x^k }{\, a (a+1) \cdots (a+k) \,} }
$$

using this continued fraction (I expect) equivalent form:

$$
\cfrac{1}{a + \cfrac{-ax}{a+1 + \cfrac{x}{a+2 + \cfrac{-(a+1)x}{a+3 + \cfrac{2x}{a+4 + \cfrac{-(a+2)x}{a+5 + \cfrac{3x}{a+6 + \cdots}}}}}}}
\, \mathrm{,}
$$

which can be expressed as

$$
\cfrac{f_0}{g_0 + \cfrac{f_1}{g_1 + \cfrac{f_2}{g_2 + \cdots}}}
\, \mathrm{,}
$$

where

$$
f_k = \left\{
\begin{aligned}
1, &&& \text{if $k=0$}\\
\frac{k}{2}x , &&& \text{if $k$ is even, $k \neq 0$} \\
-\left(a+\frac{k-1}{2} \right)x , &&& \text{if $k$ is odd}
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

[NOTE: The definition of $f_k$ was initially wrong, and has been fixed according to [one of the answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157136).]

and

$$
g_k = a + k \, \text{,}
$$

for $k \geq 0$.

I have tried to implement this continued fraction in *Mathematica*. This is what I have done:

```
f[k_, a_, x_] := If[EvenQ[k], (k/2)*x, -(a + (k - 1)/2)*x];
g[k_, a_] := a + k;
CONTFRAC[a_, x_] := 
  ContinuedFractionK[f[k, a, x] // Evaluate, 
   g[k, a] // Evaluate, {k, 0, +Infinity}];
```

Then I try

```
N[CONTFRAC[3/2, -100/3]]
```

(which should return something similar to $0.029542920686933995848485613587409381469661178405257$), but all I get is this:

[image: This is what I get]

So **how can/should I ask *Mathematica* to calculate this continued sum?**

NOTE: Why am I interested in doing that? *Mathematica* numerically calculates the value of the series with enough accuracy, but in other programming environments it is not like that for some values of $a$ and $x$ (for more details, see [this math.SE thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2454318/series-related-to-the-lower-incomplete-gamma-function-gammaa-x-with-x0)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong with your code. For one, `ContinuedFractionK` needs a cutoff maximal value of `k` to work. Second, you need to make sure that `f` only evaluates after a numerical value of `k` has been given. (Else, `EvenQ[k]` evaluates to `False`. Finally, `f[0, a, x]` evaluated to zero.

Here is some code that works:

```
f[k_Integer, a_, x_] := 
 If[EvenQ[k], If[k == 0, 1, (k/2)*x], -(a + (k - 1)/2)*x]; 
g[k_, a_] := a + k; 
CONTFRAC[a_, x_, kmax_] := 
 ContinuedFractionK[f[k, a, x], g[k, a], {k, 0, kmax}];
```

You now need to specify an `kmax` to evaluate the continued fraction, e.g.

```
N[CONTFRAC[3/2, -100/3, 100], 50]
(*0.029542920686933995848485613587409381469661178405257*)
```

You will have to vary `kmax` to check for convergence. (Either manually, or you have to write a loop.)

Comment: Thank you! I am going to change the definition of $f_k$ in the question.

I thought that Mathematica was able to numerically compute infinite continued fractions (up to a given precision).

Answer (score 3):

First things first: we have the relationship

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{a(a+1)\cdots(a+k)}=\exp(z)z^{-a}\gamma(a,z)$$

where $\gamma(a,z)$ is the [lower incomplete gamma function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2.E1), which is expressed in *Mathematica*'s notation as `Gamma[a, 0, z]`.

Having gotten that out of the way, let me present a routine that uses the [Lentz-](https://doi.org/10.1364/AO.15.000668)[Thompson-Barnett](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-9991%2886%2990046-X) algorithm to evaluate a rearranged version of the CF in the OP:

```
SetAttributes[gamlow, Listable];
gamlow[a_?InexactNumberQ, z_?InexactNumberQ] := Module[{ak, c, d, di, f, h, k, tol, t2},
   tol = 10^(-Internal`PrecAccur[{a, z}]); t2 = tol^2;
   k = 1; f = c = 1; d = 0;
   While[ak = z If[OddQ[k], -(2 a + k - 1), k]/(2 (a + k - 1) (a + k));
         di = 1 + ak  d; If[di === 0, di = t2]; d = 1/di;
         c = 1 + ak/c; If[c === 0, c = t2];
         h = c d; f *= h; k++;
         Abs[h - 1] > tol];
   Exp[-z] z^a/(a f)]
```

(This routine can be compiled, if desired.)

Let's compare with the built-in:

```
{Plot3D[gamlow[a, z], {a, 1/2, 9/2}, {z, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot3D[Gamma[a, 0, z], {a, 1/2, 9/2}, {z, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: built-in versus CF]

```
Plot3D[Abs[1 - gamlow[a, z]/Gamma[a, 0, z]], {a, 1/2, 9/2}, {z, 0, 4},
       PlotLabel -> "Relative Error", PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: relative error]